# How can i give height of the child element (img) to parent element(section)?

Tags: html, css

```
    <section class="banner container">
  <img
    src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4H4vB?ver=d252&q=0&m=8&h=600&w=1600&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&x=0&y=0&s=1898&d=712&aim=true"
    alt=""
  />
  <div class="explanation">
  <h2>Xbox Game Pass Ultimate</h2>
```

In this code height of section looks as 0. But the height of img is 600px. How can i give the height of img to its parent element which is section?

As you can see in the picture section class="banner container" has no height.

[image]

Comment: the `img` tag renders it's `height` and `width` according to the `actual image` which is fetched so the `ratio of the image on the serve` is equal to the `ratio of the img tag`

Comment: Unfortunately it has no height, you can check the picture as edit.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more of your code. The code you provided is full of unclosed tags.
i assume your code should look like this:

```
 <section class="banner container">
    <img
src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4H4vB?ver=d252&q=0&m=8&h=600&w=1600&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&x=0&y=0&s=1898&d=712&aim=true"
alt=""/>
   <div class="explanation">
      <h2>Xbox Game Pass Ultimate</h2>
   </div>
</section>
```

If you build it like that the section has the height of its containing children (img tag + h2 tag)

Comment: Yes sorry for missing part, but unfortunately section has no height, you can see the picture as edit.

Comment: if the elements are floating use a clearfix to clear the float as seen here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp